# 24V - 48V standard for lab. tips

Tags: lighting

I'm new to home improvement. Here's my question.

I've got several led strips for ~24V each and I've formulated a circuits to make them work from a 48V outlet at a lab psu. Approx. 16 ampere unregulated.

The 48V standard is a little high for safety reasons here, so I've tested for ~24V 3A per line with some success (much 50hz noise, more), but still unsure how to do cabling and terminals.

Any ideas?

Should I use straight outlet terminals at 48V for instance?

The question is.   Should I secure the installation to send straight 48V all across the place, and regulate each terminal individually, or push an already regulated ~24V at source.

What would you recomend?
What precautions should I take? ex: fuses, max current, current spikes crowbar, individual crowbars at each terminal. etc.

What would be the standards being in place for 48V lab standards for illumination and motor drivers/electronic modules?

Comment: 48 V is probably not too high for safety reasons. see also: [Extra-low voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra-low_voltage)

Answer (score 0):

The voltage limit for safety is 50VDC.

There is no difference between 48VDC and 24VDC in terms of [safety and standards](https://www.osha.gov/laws-regs/standardinterpretations/2015-09-04).

Below 50VDC is considered safe because the impedance of the body and the current flowing through the body at this voltage makes it unlikely for someone to be injured.

If you want to protect against injury, you can add a differential breaker [(residual current device)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device)